# How to input chinese characters in code page 65001 in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I find that chinese characters can be input and displayed in CMD in code page 936 in win7 and that chinese character cannot be input but can be displayed in CMD in code page 65001 in win7. Am i right?

How can I input chinese characters in CMD in code page 65001 in windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right.. Code page 65001 (or UTF-8) support all characters used in the whole world. You can change cmd code page by typing `cmd /K chcp 65001` in cmd